# Which version of python added the else clause for for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

Which was the first version of python to include the [else clause for for loops](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

I find that the python docs usually does a good job of documenting when features were added, but I can't seem to find the info on this feature. 
(It doesn't help that 'for' and 'else' are particularly difficult terms to google for on a programming website)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's been present since the beginning. To see that, get the source from alt.sources, specifically the message titled "[Python 0.9.1 part 17/21](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.sources/browse_thread/thread/74a577bbcfc4be0a/cbaaec4fbfebbbb6)". The date is Feb 21, 1991. This post included the grammar definition, which states:

```
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' exprlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
```

You might be able to find the 0.9.0 sources if you try harder than I did, but as the first public release was 0.9.0 on 20 Feb, that would get you back one day. The 0.9.1 release was a minor patch that did not affect this part of the grammar.

(Is that a [UTSL](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UTSL.html) reference or what? When was the last time *you* looked at a shar file? ;)

BTW, I reconstructed the original source and tweaked it a bit to compile under gcc-4.0 on my OS X 10.4 box. [Details](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2009/03/27/python_0_9_1p1.html) for those interested few, including [python-0.9.1.tar.gz](http://dalkescientific.com/Python/python-0.9.1.tar.gz).

The entire development history is available from version control, even after changing version control systems twice. "hg log -p -r 6:7" from the cpython Mercurial archive shows that the "for/else" was committed on Sun Oct 14 12:07:46 1990 +0000, and the previous commit was Sat Oct 13 19:23:40 1990 +0000. for/else has been part of Python since October 1990.

Answer (score 7):

It's been around since at least [1.4](http://www.python.org/doc/1.4/ref/ref7.html#HDR2), which is the [oldest version of the documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/versions/) I know of.

Comment: I came up with the same answer, just not quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.0.1, at least..

```
Python 1.0.1 (Mar 27 2009)
Copyright 1991-1994 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam
>>> for x in range(2):
...     print x
... else:
...     print "loop done"
... 
0
1
loop done
```